# Can anyone tell me how to restart dispatcher timer in c# wpf app?

Tags: wpf, timer

I am write Auction app in WPF and I don't know how to restart my DispatcherTimer,

This is code for Timer.

```
Timer = new DispatcherTimer();

Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);

Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (time > 1)
    {
        time--;
        timertxt.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60);

    }
    else
    {
        Timer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Auction is off !","Error !",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);

        AuctionIDtxt.Clear();
        Productnametxt.Clear();
        pricetxt.Clear();
        descriptiontxtblock.Clear();

        winnerislbl.IsVisible.Equals(true);
        winnerislbl.Content = "winner is:" ;
        winuserlbl.Content = UserLbl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Call `Timer.Start()`. That said, you shouldn't count seconds yourself, because timers aren't arbitrarily precise. Use DateTime and TimeSpan instead.

Comment: i called Timer.Start() in code for Load button.

Answer (score 1):

Just call Timer.Start().

> Start resets the timer Interval.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To reset the timer, you need to call Stop() and Start() [.NET Reference Source: DispatcherTimer.Start()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherTimer.cs,a3450586a3e54079)